# Creating a ContentProvider in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-contentprovider

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 and was trying to add a Content Provider component to the project. I keep getting the error "URI Authorities must be a valid URI authority" even after trying many variants of the URI Authorities entry. Same results for a brand new project shown below. Is this working in Studio or is something wrong with the entry?

[image: Android Studio Configure Component]

Comment: Have you tried to remove semicolon `;`?

Comment: Yes. Same error without the semicolon.

Comment: Same error without the "content://" and the same error without trailing /info and same error without the trailing "mycontentprovider/info". Even tried "com.example.1" and it still gives me the error.

Comment: Tried it again an it worked this time. Will accept the first answer as a correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be without `content://` prefix, as simple as `com.package.1;com.package.2`:

[image]

This will create following `<provider>` in `AndroidManifest`:

```
    <provider
        android:name="com.mydomain.MyContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.1;com.example.2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uri Authority is the string between `content://` and the next slash.

A content provider with `com.example` authority will handle any Uri starting with `content://com.example`.

A content provider cannot specify an Uri Authority that's already present in the system. Such app cannot be installed.

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI